# Partially Filled Array Null Values

Tags: java, null

so i've been brainstorming for a while now, im on my last and final step of homework. i think im actually done, it's just i need help getting rid of these null values:

here's the code:

```
public static char[] readArray(char[] words){
        char[] letters = new char[words.length];
        letters = myInput(); //get input message

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < letters.length ; i++)
             letters[i] = words[i] ; //store message to array of words

        return words;
    }
    public static char[] myInput(){
        // method to take message from user
        String myMessage;
        System.out.print("Input message: ");
        Scanner myIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        myMessage = myIn.nextLine();// Read a line of message
        return myMessage.toCharArray();
    }
    public static void printOneInLine(char[] words){
        //for every word, print them in a line
        for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++){
            if (words[i] == ' ') // words separated by space creates a new line
                System.out.println();
            else
            System.out.print(words[i]); //print the word
        }
    }
```

test case:

```
input = hello world
output =
hello
world NUL NUL NUL NUL ...
```

i know the array is partially filled and because of `i < words.length` the system tries to display values of the array from 0 - 256. Any suggestions would be gladly appreciated. PS: new to java

Comment: You should rephrase your question. What exactly do you try to achieve? What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: Why are you using `char[]` instead of `String`?

Comment: @cypressious I am trying to get rid of NUL NUL NUL NUL. I tried changing the array size, which is actually 256. It kind of work but not  what I really wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's time to simplify this: get rid of the `readArray` method, which does not add value on top of `myInput`, and use `myInput` instead. If you do this in the `main()`, it will work fine:

```
char[] words = myInput();
printOneInLine(words);
```

The rest of your code is fine as it is - no other changes are necessary ([demo](http://ideone.com/daRs2y)).

> The instruction says, method readArray should return number of characters stored in the array.

You need to change your `readArray` method as follows:

```
public static int readArray(char[] words){
    char[] letters = new char[words.length];
    letters = myInput(); //get input message

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < letters.length ; i++)
         words[i] = letters[i] ; //store message to array of words

    return letters.length;
}
```

Now your `printOneInLine` would need to change as well - it needs to take the `length` on the side, and use it in place of `words.length` to know when to stop:

```
public static void printOneInLine(char[] words, int len) {
    //for every word, print them in a line
    for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
        if (words[i] == ' ') // words separated by space creates a new line
            System.out.println();
        else
            System.out.print(words[i]); //print the character
    }
}
```

Comment: it does work, but instruction says, method `readArray` should return number of characters stored in the array. these values are then  passed on to printOneInLine method.

Comment: @BoytanodPitongulo That's because you forgot to change your main. It needs to store the int returned by the first method, and pass it to the second one.

Comment: i think its the return value that's causing the problem. If i return an integer, then for printOneInLine(char[] words, int len) there won't be a value for char[] anymore. check: http://ideone.com/gUJhWR

Comment: @BoytanodPitongulo No, it's an error in your `readArray` method ([demo](http://ideone.com/08RSOo)).

Comment: did you notice that if i put "hello world" it doesnt print the same exact words?

Comment: @BoytanodPitongulo It does for me (see the demo).